# Struts2 tiles org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener NullPointerException error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2, tiles

I'm trying to get my Struts2 project running with Tiles and Tomcat server but I just can't get it working.

I've looked at the documentation for both and I think i'm doing it right. here are my files:
 web.xml

```
<display-name>Struts2_Application</display-name>
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <result-types>
         <result-type name="tiles" 
         class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
      </result-types>


      <action name="*Menu" method="{1}" 
         class="com.greensun.struts2.tiles.action.MenuAction">
         <result name="tiger" type="tiles">tiger</result>
         <result name="lion" type="tiles">lion</result>
      </action>

   </package>
</struts>
```

MenuAction.java

```
public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport {

/**
 * 
 */
/*private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "tiger";
}*/

public String tiger() { return "tiger"; }
public String lion() { return "lion"; }
  }
```

When i try to run the project I get this error:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart Critical: Class
>   org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener Exception sending context
>   initialized event to listener instance of
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesContextFactory.createApplicationContext(ChainedTilesContextFactory.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory$StrutsTilesContextFactory.createApplicationContext(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:68)
>   at
>   org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createTilesContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:199)
>   at
>   org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.tiles.listener.TilesListener.createContainer(TilesListener.java:91)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener.createContainer(StrutsTilesListener.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.tiles.listener.TilesListener.contextInitialized(TilesListener.java:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> I'm sure i'm doing something really stupid but I can't see it myself.
>   Anyone?

Comment: Which version of Struts2 and Tiles?

Comment: Where is your tiles.xml file?...paste that too